# Using Newton Raphson method to find x2 and x3

Tags: calculus, numerical-methods, newton-raphson

I have the following question where I am asked to find the values of $x_2$ and $x_3$:

> [image]

Here is my attempt is this correct?

> [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track

$$
f(x) = x + \frac{1}{2}\sin(2x) -\frac{\pi}{4} \\
f'(x) = 1 + \cos(2x)
$$

So that

$$
x_{n+1} = x_n -\frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}
$$

These are the first few iterations

$$
\begin{array}{c|c}\hline
n & x_n \\ \hline
0 & 0.4 \\
1 & 0.415748 \\
2 & 0.415856 \\
3 & 0.415856 \\ \hline
\end{array}
$$

If you go to Wolfram Sandbox you can enter this code to get the first 10 iterations

```
f[x_] := x + Sin[2x]/2 -\[Pi]/4;
fp[x_] := 1 + Cos[2x];

NestList[(#-f[#]/fp[#])&, 0.4, 10]
```

Comment: Do I need to put my calculator in radian mode ?

Comment: @Dan Yes!! It should be in radian mode

Comment: okay thanks a lot!

Comment: @Dan The problem was not the radian mode or not but the wrong order of calculation.

Answer (score 1):

You made the following mistake:

You have calculated

$$\frac{(0.4-0.4+0.5\cdot \sin(2*0.4)-\pi/4)}{1+\cos(2\cdot0.4)}=\frac{0.4267}{1.967}$$

I would fist calculate $$\frac{x_0+0.5\cdot \sin(2\cdot x_0)-\pi/4}{1+\cos(2\cdot x_0)}$$

and then substract this result from $x_0.$

For $x_0=0.4$ we get

$$\frac{0.4+0.5\cdot \sin(2\cdot 0.4)-\pi/4}{1+\cos(2\cdot 0.4)}=-0.015748$$ -

Substracting: $0.40000-(-0.01575)=0.40000+0.015748=0.415748$